# Format scientific notation in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

Is it possible to format numbers in scientific notation as exponents with the base 10 rather than E in Excel? 
For example, Excel converts 0.00123 to 1.23E3, but I would like the format [image: 1.23x10^3]

Comment: I fine-tuned my answer with the complete formula.

Comment: Search the reverse convert only arrive at your convert question, so a reference for the reverse convert may benefit for likewise people: ```=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(D2,"*10^","E+"))*1```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible by using the standard number formatting in Excel.

You could of course convert your number to a text string with `=TEXT(A1;"0.00E+00")`, and then you can convert this text string to a new text string in the format that you want. It gets a bit tricky with the superscripts, as you have to display these with the `UNICHAR` function (this function is available since Excel 2013).

The Unicode values to use with the function are the following (from superscript 0 till 9):
`8304,185,178,179,8308,8309,8310,8311,8312,8313`

So superscript 50 would be `=UNICHAR(8309)&UNICHAR(8304)`

You can create elsewhere in your workbook a named range with this values, so the conversion would be easy with an `INDEX`.
Actually, I would create two ranges, one for the first digit of the exponent (where you don't have a 0, but an empty string, as you don't want to display 10^03 but 10^3), and the second one for the second digit of the exponent (where you keep the 0).

To summarize:

- Convert the number to a text sting with `=TEXT(A1;"0.00E+00")`
- Replace the "E" with "x"
- Replace the "+" with "10"
- If number is negative, add a `-`
- Replace the two last characters with the corresponding superscript (convert back to number with `NUMBERVALUE()` and then use `INDEX()` to get the Unicode value to feed into the `UNICHAR` function.

So for the last digit, the formula is (the named range for the Unicode values is EXPO1 and EXPO2 in my case):
`=UNICHAR(INDEX(EXPO2;1;NUMBERVALUE(RIGHT(A1;1))+1))`
For the first digit of the exponent (i.e. the one but last character of the text string), use this formula to convert into superscript:
`=UNICHAR(INDEX(EXPO1;1;NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(RIGHT(A1;2);1)+1)))`

I am a bit lazy here, I could use `MID` as well instead of the `LEFT/RIGHT` combination. And please note that the named range is now EXPO1, where the first value is the Unicode value of the empty string (8203).

The entire formula is:
`=LEFT(TEXT(A1;"0.00E+00");4)&
"x10"&
UNICHAR(INDEX(EXPO1;1;NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(RIGHT(TEXT(A1;"0.00E+00");2);1)+1)))&
UNICHAR(INDEX(EXPO2;1;NUMBERVALUE(RIGHT(TEXT(A1;"0.00E+00");1))+1))`

with EXPO1 and EXPO2 the named ranges as explained above.

To make the formula completely self-sustained, you can hardcode these into the formula, so this becomes then :
`=LEFT(TEXT(A1;"0.00E+00");4)&
"x10"&
UNICHAR(INDEX({8203,185,178,179,8308,8309,8310,8311,8312,8313};1;NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(RIGHT(TEXT(A1;"0.00E+00");2);1)+1)))&
UNICHAR(INDEX({8304,185,178,179,8308,8309,8310,8311,8312,8313};1;NUMBERVALUE(RIGHT(TEXT(A1;"0.00E+00");1))+1))`

Finally, please note that the formula is dependent on how you convert the number into text. Per OP initial question, I used 2 digits precision after the comma (`"0.00E+00"`). If you want to display more, you have to extract more than 4 characters with the first `LEFT` formula in my example.

Answer (score 1):

Building on Peter K's reply...
If you put this formula in **B1**:

```
=TEXT(A1,"0.00#E+0")
```

And the below formula in **C1** then it will handle **negative exponents**:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(TEXT(A1,"0.00E+00"),5),"E","")&
"x10"&
IF(COUNTIF(B1,"*E-*"),UNICHAR(8315),"")&
UNICHAR(INDEX({8203,185,178,179,8308,8309,8310,8311,8312,8313},1,NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(RIGHT(TEXT(A1,"0.00E+00"),2),1)+1)))&
UNICHAR(INDEX({8304,185,178,179,8308,8309,8310,8311,8312,8313},1,NUMBERVALUE(RIGHT(TEXT(A1,"0.00E+00"),1))+1))
```

Further, if you want **three** digit precision after the decimal instead of **two** then in the **first line** change this portion from `LEFT(TEXT(A1,"0.00E+00"),5)` to `LEFT(TEXT(A1,"0.000E+00"),6)`.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use VBA (Visual Basic for Applications).

I created a VBA macro (https://github.com/hisakatha/exp2superscript) to convert exponents into superscripts via text formatting function.
This macro can be imported in the Excel's Visual Basic for Applications editor and registered in Excel Add-ins, and then the macro can be called in Excel.

Briefly, the macro replaces "E" with "×10" using the VBA `Replace` function and format the exponent part of numbers as superscripts using an assignment:
`<cell>.Characters(Start:=<index of the exponent>).Font.Superscript = True`

Answer (score 0):

I improved the previous answer from Peter K.
Now it includes the minus sign on the power, auto-setting of 1 to 3 digits for the power, and also zero power value for integer numbers.

It works when ";" is the Excel list and function parameters separator. Replace ";" by "," if required, based on your own Excel configuration.

I use the LET function to better understand the formula.
It allows us to create a list of [names; values/formula] pairs.

Numeric value to convert is set at A1 cell.
`

```
=LET(valor;Q12;
template;"0,00E+000";
nro;TEXT(valor;template);
base;LEFT(nro;FIND("E";nro)-1);
signoExp;IF(LEFT(RIGHT(TEXT(valor;template);4);1)="-";UNICHAR(8315);"");
powD1;NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(RIGHT(TEXT(valor;template);3);1));
powD2;NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(RIGHT(TEXT(valor;template);2);1));
powD3;NUMBERVALUE(RIGHT(TEXT(valor;template);1));
superDigits;{8304;185;178;179;8308;8309;8310;8311;8312;8313};
expS1;UNICHAR(INDEX(superDigits;powD1+1;1));
expS2;UNICHAR(INDEX(superDigits;powD2+1;1));
expS3;UNICHAR(INDEX(superDigits;powD3+1;1));
IF(valor<>"";base&"x10"&signoExp&
RIGHT(expS1&expS2&expS3;LEN(powD1*100+powD2*10+powD3));""))
```

`

https://ucao365-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/waltereberle_uca_edu_ar/EblCkDyPxtpMjD3Pur8rzWkBACfeiQYlUAbNMjgFU9KFoQ?e=3HyfoE

Comment: Spanish formula translation:
=VALOR.NUMERO(IZQUIERDA(TEXTO(A2;"0,00E+00");4))&
"x10"&SI(IZQUIERDA(DERECHA(TEXTO(A2;"0,00E+00");3);1)="-";UNICAR(8315);"")&SI(VALOR.NUMERO(IZQUIERDA(DERECHA(TEXTO(A2;"0,00E+00");2);1))<>0;UNICAR(INDICE({8304;185;178;179;8308;8309;8310;8311;8312;8313};VALOR.NUMERO(IZQUIERDA(DERECHA(TEXTO(A2;"0,00E+00");2);1))+1;1));"")&SI(VALOR.NUMERO(DERECHA(TEXTO(A2;"0,00E+00");1))<>0;UNICAR(INDICE({8304;185;178;179;8308;8309;8310;8311;8312;8313;8314;8315};VALOR.NUMERO(DERECHA(TEXTO(A2;"0,00E+00");1))+1;1));UNICAR(8304))